# search string and use output path to search same string

Tags: python

I have situation where I need to generate report from actual given path and search string and whatever output I get use that path to search same string until it ends..

i.e.

I have path (script) like this `/home/xyz/abc/efg`

I want to find `"string"` from `/home/xyz/abc/efg`

Let's say output is like `/home/bla/bla` -- then use that output to search `"string"` from `/home/bla/bla`.

If it finds from `/home/bla/bla` - as `/home/test/test1` then search string from `/home/test/test1`

Keep repeating that until loop ends and generate output for each find related to parent find.

Let me know if this make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not at all clear. Is `/home/xyz/abc/efg` a Python script? A text file? A directory? Where are you expecting `"string"` to be stored - in a single file? In one of many files? In many of many files? What is the output - the file name where your search string was found? Please [edit] your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where we can see **exactly** what you're looking for.

Comment: Additionally, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).